# How to save values from array of pointers to structs in EEPROM

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, avr

I am trying to save all the values from 4 structs to my ATMega328P EEPROM using the standard Arduino EEPROM-Library Routine EEPROM.put() and retrieve them via EEPROM.get(). How Can i pass all the values from my value_table to these functions? Here is how my data looks like.

```
typedef struct EXAMPLE {
  uint8_t part1[7][2];
  uint8_t part2[3];
} *ptr[5];


EXAMPLE VALUE_1 = {{
  {1, 8},  
  {2, 9}, 
  {3, 10}, 
  {4, 11}, 
  {5, 12}, 
  {6, 13},  
  {7, 14} 
},
  {15, 16, 17} 
};
```

There are four versions VALUE_1 to VALUE_4 combined in an Array of pointers.

```
struct EXAMPLE *value_table[] = {&VALUE_1, &VALUE_2, &VALUE_3, &VALUE_4};
```

Here is what i have come up with, but yields faulty results.

```
EEPROM.put(0, &value_table); // 0 is first byte of EEPROM
EEPROM.get(0, value_table);
```

What i want to store is the values located in VALUE_1 - VALUE_4 to make them persistent.

I am very thankful for every hint!

Comment: The pointers are probably killing you. If I'm reading that right, you've told `put` to write 4 pointers, not the data at the pointers, into the EEPROM.

Comment: Yes, thats probably right. But there must be a way to get the values and pass them to `put`? Writing and reading the the elements separately to the EEPROM like `EEPROM.put(0,VALUE_1)`works, but this can not be right...

Comment: @user3750030: nope, it stores the data you give it. If you give it 4 pointers, it will store 4 pointers (and no data). It has no idea what is the internal structure of `value_table`, it just gets `sizeof(value_table)` and stores so many bytes to EEPROM. Actually now I have strong suspicion your original code stores only the single VALUE_1 pointer, not the other three of them. Hard to tell from that dumb-down docs. What's the problem with storing them separately exactly? You can still do a `for` over pointer array (check my code, it screams for `i` substitution).

Comment: @user3750030 Why do you not think putting each piece of data exactly where you want it is right?

Comment: @Ped7g you were dead right on the one pointer. I downloaded the Arduino toolkit and read the code. You're also right that the documentation sucks. Fortunately we have [a new tool to deal with that](http://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation). Unfortunately neither of us know this smurf well enough to write it. Yet.

Comment: @user4581301 well, I'm pretty sure *every* bit of my post is correct and right (although sometimes rarely I do a mistake, especially as I write these things just from head in my spare time to relax a bit from real work and in this case I'm answering about technology I had never met before). So I sort of don't understand what's the hesitation about, but feel free to take your own pace, to understand it. Those answers are not going anywhere (as long as SO web works). UPS, I mistaken you for OP ;) (that's that rare mistake moment)

Comment: Considering both our answers are preaching the same logic and solution we're in agreement. I'm just saying I don't know Arduino well enough to try writing a manual on how to program it

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing:

```
// writing (starting at some "eeprom_address" address)
int eeprom_address = 0;
EEPROM.put(eeprom_address + 0*sizeof(EXAMPLE), VALUE_1);
EEPROM.put(eeprom_address + 1*sizeof(EXAMPLE), VALUE_2);
EEPROM.put(eeprom_address + 2*sizeof(EXAMPLE), VALUE_3);
EEPROM.put(eeprom_address + 3*sizeof(EXAMPLE), VALUE_4);

// reading
EEPROM.get(eeprom_address + 0*sizeof(EXAMPLE), VALUE_1);
EEPROM.get(eeprom_address + 1*sizeof(EXAMPLE), VALUE_2);
EEPROM.get(eeprom_address + 2*sizeof(EXAMPLE), VALUE_3);
EEPROM.get(eeprom_address + 3*sizeof(EXAMPLE), VALUE_4);

// plus set the value_table in the same way as before
struct EXAMPLE *value_table[] = {&VALUE_1, &VALUE_2, &VALUE_3, &VALUE_4};
```

There's no point to store pointers into EEPROM, you should store only data values (but in a structured way, so you know which byte belongs to which data item, and can read them properly into target variables).

If you would want to work with single struct, do the `struct EXAMPLE value_table[] = {VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3, VALUE_4};`. But this will copy the VALUE_1 into the value_table, so it will eat twice as much memory as having only single VALUE_1 around.

BTW, the documentation just says "EEPROM.get(address, data)" without types... is this still C/C++? :/ *frown*

Doc link: [get](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMGet), [put](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMPut), there are also `struct` examples.

BTW: `int` for address used only as a copy of official documentation, I would personally NEVER use `int` for address of course, suddenly my plan to check Arduino at some distant future point gets much more distant.

---

Writing with `for` variant:

```
constexpr size_t VALUES_N = 4;
struct EXAMPLE *value_table[] = {&VALUE_1, &VALUE_2, &VALUE_3, &VALUE_4};
// writing (starting at some "eeprom_address" address)
int eeprom_address = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < VALUES_N; ++i) {
    EEPROM.put(eeprom_address + i*sizeof(EXAMPLE), *(value_table[i]));
}

// reading
for (size_t i = 0; i < VALUES_N; ++i) {
    EEPROM.get(eeprom_address + i*sizeof(EXAMPLE), *(value_table[i]));
}
```

Comment: I think it's C++ with `get` and `put` being templates. Note the lack of a size parameter.

Comment: @user4581301 hmm... so any newbie not aware of what is going on inside will use this for millions of custom structs, wondering why the code size skyrocketed (or maybe just gets a bit bigger, depends probably how that template is written)? \*frowns\* even more. Oh well, thanks for the info anyway. :)

Comment: I looked around for a copy of the header, but couldn't find one. The Arduino is kind of Embedded Systems for Dummies (Not a bad thing unto itself), so ease of programming and type safety trumps many other considerations. If I;'m building something safety critical I like it when the toolchain makes it harder for me to kill someone.

Comment: Yeah, but I think they dumbed it down to a point, where it actually becomes more dangerous... Well, hard to tell, probably easier to hop on ... which in C/C++ learning means you will shoot your legs sooner and with explosive rounds. :D ... ok, I can see the point... but I \*FROWN\* ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded Arduino and took a look at `get` and `put`. As expected they're templated

```
template< typename T > T &get( int idx, T &t )
template< typename T > const T &put( int idx, const T &t )
```

Because they have a reference to parameter of template-defined type, they know the size and pretty much everything else they need to perform the read or write on the EEPROM.

Hoping somewhere down the line `put` throws an exception on write fail because I don't see any `throw` or other error notification method, but that's not a concern here.

So...

```
struct EXAMPLE *value_table[] = {&VALUE_1, &VALUE_2, &VALUE_3, &VALUE_4};
```

is an array of 4 pointers to structures, not the structures itself. This means

```
sizeof(value_table);
```

is going to be four times the size of a pointer, probably 16 bytes on an Arduino. But

```
EEPROM.put(0, &value_table);
```

won't even write that. Because it passes in a pointer to `value_table`, all that will be written is a single pointer, which because of how arrays work, will be a pointer to the first entry, which is a pointer to the data to be stored.

`get` and `put` take the data by reference, so explicitly taking a pointer isn't necessary. And unfortunately because the template will take just about anything there is no compiler warning or error to catch this mistake.

To `put`, you have two choices:

```
EEPROM.put(0, VALUE_1 );
EEPROM.put(sizeof(VALUE_1), VALUE_2);
EEPROM.put(sizeof(VALUE_1)*2, VALUE_3);
...
EEPROM.put(sizeof(VALUE_1)*(N-1), VALUE_N);
```

or a loop which performs the same, or replace the table of pointers to the EXAMPLE structure with a table of the EXAMPLE structure .

```
struct EXAMPLE value_table[] = 
{
    {
        {
            {1, 8},  
            {2, 9}, 
            {3, 10}, 
            {4, 11}, 
            {5, 12}, 
            {6, 13},  
            {7, 14} 
        },
        {15, 16, 17} 
    },
    {
        // contents of VALUE_2
    },
    {
        // contents of VALUE_3
    },
    ...
    {
        // contents of VALUE_N
    }
}
```

`VALUE_1` etc... are discarded.

Instead either use `value_table[x]` where `x` is the value number -1 or define

```
enum VALUES
{
    VALUE_1 = 0,
    VALUE_2,
    VALUE_3,
    ...
    VALUE_N
}
```

and access the table as `value_table[VALUE_1]`. This approach is a bit more long-winded, but a lot easier to read.

The call to `put` remains similar to what's currently used and just loses the address of operator.

```
EEPROM.put(0, value_table);
```

Using `get` will be extremely similar

```
EEPROM.get(0, VALUE_1 );
EEPROM.get(sizeof(VALUE_1), VALUE_2);
EEPROM.get(sizeof(VALUE_1)*2, VALUE_3);
...
EEPROM.get(sizeof(VALUE_1)*(N-1), VALUE_N);
```

or

```
EEPROM.get(0, value_table);
```

depending on the method chosen to handle `put`.

Comment: As I told you .. dumbed down to a point where it becomes easier to shoot yourself into foot (And that's quite a feat, as pure C/C++ is like high performance suicide tool for newcomer with no safety net :) ). The unix `write(...)` at least forces you to specify size, so you have to have some idea what your memory structure looks like, here you can do `&value_table` and compiler will not even wink at you. :)